# In SQL Server, how to replace the seconds value with another value?

Tags: sql-server-2012

How do I replace the seconds portion?

```
2016-07-07 16:46:23.057
```

I want to replace 23 with 00:

```
2016-07-07 16:46:00.057
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
DECLARE @Date datetime = '2016-07-07 16:46:23.057' 
DECLARE @NewSeconds int = 0 -- from 0 to 59 - what you want to replace the original seconds with
DECLARE @NewDate datetime

SET @NewDate = DATEADD(ss, @NewSeconds, DATEADD(ss, -DATEPART(ss, @Date), @Date))

SELECT @NewDate
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set @new_value = dateadd(s, -datepart(s, @old_value), @old_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select CONVERT(varchar(10),getdate(),121) +' ' + right('00'+cast(DATEPART(HOUR,getdate()) as varchar(4)),2)+ ':' + right('00'+cast(DATEPART(MINUTE,getdate()) as varchar(4)),2)+  ':00:' + right('000'+cast(DATEPART(MS,getdate()) as varchar(4)),3)
```